# Why doesn't the difference between two dates give me a whole number of days

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain this to me. From jconsole ...

```
from = new Date('01/01/2010')
Fri Jan 01 2010 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)

thru = new Date('06/07/2010')
Mon Jun 07 2010 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PST)

(thru - from) / (1000 * 24 * 60 * 60)
156.95833333333334
```

Why don't I get a whole number of days? How do I calculate the difference between two dates?

thanks much.

Comment: Did you notice that the timezones in your dates are different?

Comment: wanted to understand why/what is happening here so I can round it up or down. Don't want to end up with a day less or more

Comment: both are PST, why do you say they are different

Comment: Look at my answer, ash34. Lots more detail there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your first date is coming out as GMT -0800, the second is GMT -0700 - that's a 1 hour difference, which is 0.041666 of a day - exactly the amount you're off by.

This may have to do with daylight savings time differences, since one of your dates is in January and the other is in June; thus one would be on daylight savings and the other would be off it. (And GMT -0800 is PST when not on daylight savings; GMT -0700 is PST when on daylight savings.)

You should be safe to simply round to the nearest integral number of days, since daylight savings will never vary by more than an hour in either direction.

Comment: You probably want to actually round, since if the daylight savings difference were going the other way (Jun to Jan, instead of Jan to Jun), you'd actually be a bit above the target number.

Comment: No. When we adjust the clock up by an hour (GMT -0700) Math.ceil rounds it upwards. When we adjust the clock back by an hour (GMT -0800), Math.ceil would have no effect.

Comment: When the clock goes back by an hour, you'll get a result which is 0.041666 above an integer (say, 156.041666). `ceil` will take that up to to 157, as opposed to 156 which would be the correct number.

Answer (score 1):

This should get the whole number of days between the dates even if there are daylight savings (or just timezone) differences, and there's no scary rounding. Rounding is scary to me because it's taking an answer I don't like and fudging it, whereas this calculates exactly what I meant to calculate.

```
// assuming this date and the other date are date only
Date.prototype.daysSince = function(other) {
    // get the timezone difference between then and now (in minutes)
    var dstDiff = other.getTimezoneOffset() - this.getTimezoneOffset();
    // convert the timezone different to milliseconds
    var dstDiffMs = dstDiff * 60 * 100;
    // get the milliseconds difference between the two dates
    var diff = this.valueOf() - other.valueOf() + dstDiffMs;
    // convert to days
    var days = diff / 86400000; // or 60*60*24*1000 if you prefer
    return days;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript does not do floating point math the way one would expect. It is not clever enough to round up to what you want to see.
For a simple fix do

```
Math.ceil((thru - from) / (1000 * 24 * 60 * 60))
```

Secondly, there will be a difference in milliseconds between the dates.
You can normalise using

```
thru.setHours(0,0,0,0);
```

and

```
from.setHours(0,0,0,0);
```

before using them

Comment: Ahem - Math.ceil seems to be better than Math.round - sorry
Also there is the matter of DST I did not notice you crossed